# Existence of an explosive prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, experimental-mathematics, discrete-dynamical-systems

The motivation to introduce *explosive prime* is [Carmichael's totient conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael%27s_totient_function_conjecture) (see why below).

Let $\mathbb{N}_{SF}$ be the set of positive square-free integers. Consider the map $f:\mathbb{N}_{SF} \to \mathbb{N}_{SF}$ defined by $$ f(n)=\prod_{\substack{p \text{ prime, with} \\ p|n \text{ or } (p-1)|n}} p.$$
Let us iterate this map and consider the sequences of the form $(f^{(r)}(n))_r$. Note that $n$ divides $f(n)$, so this sequence is weakly increasing. If it is strictly increasing then $n$ is called *explosive* (otherwise the sequence is eventually constant).

*Example:* $(f^{(r)}(1))_r = (1, \ 2, \ 2^1 3, \  2^1 3^1 7, \  2^1 3^1 7^1 43, \ 2^1 3^1 7^1 43, \dots)$ is eventually constant.

Let $u_r(n)$ be the numbers of prime factors of $f^{(r)}(n)$, with $r \ge 0$. Then for example:

- $(u_r(1))_r = (0,1,2,3,4,4,\dots)$,
- $(u_r(5))_r = (1, 2, 4, 9, 77, \dots)$.

Observe that the numbers of divisors of $f^{(4)}(5)$ is $2^{77} > 10^{23} $, so $u_5(5)$ should be huge, while its computation is unreachable directly. Then $5$ *looks* explosive, but a proof seems unreachable too.

What may be reachable is the proof (by contradiction) of the existence of an explosive prime.

**Question 1**: Is there an explosive prime?

It should be useful to recall that the density of primes of the form $m+1$ with $m$ square-free (in the set of all primes) is about $1/3$, more precisely Artin's constant (see why [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4378498/84284)):

$$
c_{Artin}:= \prod_{p \ prime} (1-\frac{1}{(p-1)p}) = 0.3739558136192\dots
$$

It is good to mention that the statement "$13$ and $2287$ are explosive" implies [Carmichael's totient conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael%27s_totient_function_conjecture), see why in [this paper](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Eford/wwwpapers/totients.pdf) by Kevin Ford (on page 38): $13$ goes to his case I (as $13 = 12 \times 1 + 1$) and $2287$ to his case II (as $2287 = 18 \times 127 +1$ and $127 = 18 \times 7 + 1$). But above statement looks true experimentally:

- $(u_r(13))_r = (1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 24,\dots)$,
- $(u_r(2287))_r = (1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 24,\dots)$.

I checked that $u_6(13)>10000$, whereas $2^{10000}>10^{3000}$, so $u_7(13)$ should be *really* huge.

Finally, about the density of explosive primes in the set of all primes: among the $168$ primes less than $1000$, $119$ ones *looks* explosive (as $13$), i.e. more than $70 \%$. Here are the $49$ other ones (which are non-explosive, confirmed): $2, 3, 7, 19, 43, 67, 79, 97, 127, 163, 193, 211, 223, 307, 317, 337, 349, 409, 421, 463, 487, 499, 521, 523, 541, 547, 569, 571, 617, 631, 643, 673, 691, 709, 733, 739, 757, 787, 809, 811, 823, 839, 853, 857, 859, 883, 919, 967, 997.$

Assuming that Question 1 has a positive answer:
**Question 2**: What is the density of explosive primes in the set of all primes?

My guess is that the set of explosive primes is infinite, but of density zero in the set of all primes, and also that a proof of these two statements is reachable.

Experimentally, there is $c>0$ such that the number of *looking* explosive primes less than $n$ is about $c\frac{n}{\log(n)^2}$ for $n$ large enough, as for the [Sophie Germain primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_and_Sophie_Germain_primes) or the [twin primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime), but with a different constant $c$ (apparently): $c=1$ for the explosive ones, $c \sim 1.32032$ (more precisely, two times the [Hardy–Littlewood's twin prime constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture)) for the other ones. The following table provides the counting of such primes between $10^n$ and $10^n + 10^6$ for $n=23,24,25$, together with the prediction of the estimate for $c=1$ and $c=1.32032$:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c} n & \# \text{ Explosive} & c=1 & \# \text{ Sophie Germain} & \# \text{ Twin} & c=1.32032 \newline \hline
22& 421 &   374 &   470 &   522 &   494 \newline \hline
23& 346 &   343 &   494 &   456 &   452\newline \hline
24& 342 &   315 &   428 &   419 &   426\newline \hline
25& 259 &   291 &   407 &   451 &   384
\end{array}$$

Comment: I always thought of 168 as of the cardinal of the second smallest simple group. Nice to learn that it is also the number of primes smaller than 1000.

Comment: I always thought of 168 as the place where you could transfer between the 1 and the A. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/168th_Street_station_(New_York_City_Subway)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/168_(number)

Comment: That reminds me a bit my investigations about the map $n\mapsto nr_{0}(n)$, whose the sequence of iterates gets constant if some term thereof is half the sum of twin primes, perhaps the same kind of tools could be used in both problems.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: can you put a link to what you are talking about?

Comment: Heuristically the number of primes $p < n$ for which $u_5(p) > 5$ is also $O(\frac{n}{\log^2 n})$. Does your heuristic assume that if the process gets bootstrapped by a prime in $\{d + 1 | d \textrm{ is a factor of } 1806p\}$ then it will be explosive?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux : I vainly tried to find one, unfortunately I don't remember on which website (MO or MSE) I asked the considered question nor its title.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Sorry my use of "heuristically" is no proper, I should say "experimentally": I counted $342$ primes *looking* explosive between $10^{24}$ and $10^{24} + 10^6$, and $259$ ones between $10^{25}$ and $10^{25} + 10^6$, whereas this heuristic with $c=1$ predicts $(315,291)$. FYI, I counted $(407, 428)$ Sophie Germain primes, and $(451,419)$ twin primes, in these intervals, whereas their heuristic (with $c=1.32032\dots$) predicts $(426,384)$. About your comment, can you elaborate? $1806 = 2^13^17^143$, ok but $6$ is a factor of $1806p$ (for all $p$) whereas $7$ is not explosive.

Comment: Typos: $(407, 428)$ should be $(428,407)$, and $(451,419)$ should be $(419,451)$.

Comment: Perhaps it would be clearer as $\{dp + 1 | d \textrm{ is a factor of } 1806\}$. Any initial $p$ will accumulate primes $2, 3, 7, 43$ merely by being a multiple of $1$, but the expected number of further primes accumulated is $O(\frac1{\log p})$ (and picking up one more prime doesn't guarantee explosion).

Comment: @PeterTaylor: in my computation I iterated the map $f$ to get at least twelve new primes (except if the sequence becomes constant, of course). Even then, nothing guarantee explosion (otherwise that would provide a proof to Carmichael's totient conjecture). We can just say that the initial prime *looks* explosive.

Comment: I think $\operatorname{rad}(p^2)=p$ for a prime, so it is not the square-free part. Which do you mean?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich: You are right, square-free part is confusing (I will remove that), I just mean the [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) as defined on this link, i.e. the biggest square-free divisor.